# How to write one new line in Bitbucket markdown?

Tags: newline, markdown, bitbucket

Is it possible to write a new line (NOT a paragraph) in the Bitbucket markdown?

Two new lines in the source creates one new paragraph. I only want a new line. And I don't want to use a code block.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

It's possible, as addressed in [Issue #7396](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/7396/the-text-editor-is-losing-line-breaks):

> When you do want to insert a `<br />` break tag using Markdown, you **end a line with two or more spaces, then type <kbd>return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>**.

Comment: While it works, please chime in at the link below or anywhere else so they change the format to something more common. https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/7396/the-text-editor-is-losing-line-breaks

Comment: This is troublesome when the editor auto-remove trailing spaces.

Comment: there are problem with phpstorm when want to git commit. that remove space from end of line some time!

Comment: I wish they'd also implement the [backslash solution](https://gist.github.com/shaunlebron/746476e6e7a4d698b373#gistcomment-2271765).

Comment: Write `<br/>` explicitly.

Answer (score 90):

It's now possible to add a forced line break
with **two blank spaces at the end of the line**:

```
line1→→
line2
```

*will be formatted as:*

line1
line2

Comment: in case you're not seeing the special characters on your browser/platform: → is an arrow and should represent a blank space

Comment: This likely works in other markdown documents as well

Comment: I'd never do this because all text files should have stripped whitespace everywhere (except the trailing newline). Using meaningful space in this way is too implicit.

Comment: @AndiDog still better than a <br/>

Comment: @auco Can you elaborate on why this is the case?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue in bitbucket, and this worked for me:

```
line1
##<2 white spaces><enter>
line2
```

Comment: this places an extra blank link between line1 and line2 in bitbucket readme.md files

Answer (score 0):

On Github, `<p>` and `<br/>`solves the problem.

`<p>`I want to this to appear in a new line. Introduces extra line above

or

`<br/>` another way

Comment: Not relevant to the question, which is asking about BitBucket

Comment: This does not work in BitBucket. Note that BitBucket is a really lackluster platform, so assuming GitHub/Lab features are present in BitBucket is almost always wrong. For example, for a very long time (easily 10 years) BitBucket didn't even have syntax colouring in side-by-side view (but did in combined view). This was only added very recently (after your answer was posted).

Answer (score 0):

Feb 3rd 2020:

- Atlassian Bitbucket v5.8.3 local installation.
- I wanted to add a new line around an horizontal line.  `---` did produce the line, but I could not get new lines to work with suggestions above.
- note: I did not want to use the `[space][space]` suggestion, since my editor removes trailing spaces on save, and I like this feature on.

I ended up doing this:

```
TEXT...
<br><hr><br>
TEXT...
```

Resulting in:

```
TEXT...
<AN EMPTY LINE>
----------------- AN HORIZONTAL LINE ----------------
<AN EMPTY LINE>
TEXT...
```

Comment: "March 2nd 2020" Are you from the future or am I in the past?

Comment: oups, reversed the 2 and the 3.  US: month/day/year, Canada: day/monty/year.  Correction done.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a single hyphen "-":

```
Example:
First line
-
Second line

Result:
First line

Second line
```

Comment: This creates bullet points for me, even when nothing is next to the hyphen.