# Correct syntax for newline in Github Bio

Tags: github

Here is an example on my github profile - https://github.com/jack17529

I want to change this -

`Silver Bullet in Issue KILLING.____ 
Master Mind to create Issues.______
My strongest language is Python not English.`

I want to have newline instead of blanks.

like this -

`Silver Bullet in Issue KILLING.
Master Mind to create Issues.
My strongest language is Python not English.`

I have checked Bitbucket Bio is nowhere related to Github Bio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write one new line in Bitbucket markdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385334/how-to-write-one-new-line-in-bitbucket-markdown)

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff I tried everything in the post nothing worked, I maybe wrong please be kind and write an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As told to me by github support there is no way !, see here -

[According to Github Support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvwdT.jpg)

Answer (score 21):

Maybe they don't allow us to do it via the normal way, But It is possible to do of course. We can use the *auto newline rule for the words which are too long for appending to the current line*, for our need. All we need to do is putting other [Unicode Spaces](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html) instead of normal space. And normal space between lines, for using newline rule against forbidden newline rule.

And if you want a free line, because of the character limitations, you can use the longer one;

> " " instead of " "      *(Try selecting spaces between quotes with your mouse)*

Also this trick allows me create unnecessary spaces in the Stack Overflow too, like above, in the quote box.

Here is the result: [github.com/cosmicog](https://github.com/cosmicog):
[image]

I have tried other answers, html ways, but no, they handle html tricks of course.

Note: This causes a bad look in the list view and the profile overview tooltip:
[image]
Maybe that is why it is not allowed but I hope they will fix this in the future.

Answer (score 11):

I just did it by simply copying and pasting the character corresponding to this codepoint [| unicode-table.com |](https://unicode-table.com/en/2003/) as many time as needed in order to align the text the way I wanted.

This is the procedure I followed: at the end of each line I pressed `Enter`, then I filled the new line with 7 instances of the character mentioned above; then I pressed `Enter` again and started the new line with its text.

Answer (score 3):

This question is a little stale, but I found it before I solved this myself, so I thought I'd drop my solution.

The bio doesn't appear to honor markdown, but neither does it accept HTML entities or elements. I worked around this with non-breaking characters to create long "words" similar to how you've used "_".

You can see in [my bio](https://github.com/cubap) that I needed a " " and a "‑" to format mine. The long word will pop to the next line. If you have a real short line, you can extend it with a lot of non-breaking spaces, but this probably isn't necessary. Since you cannot enter " " you need to use copy/paste or ALT codes (not looked up, but someone might add these for you). Those are the real characters above, so you can take them from this answer.

Comment: There is always a way :) If you're on mac you can use Option (Alt) + Space to insert non-breaking spaces

Answer (score 3):

Refer: [How to create newline in Github Bio](https://github.com/ewfian/How-to-create-newline-in-Github-Bio)

Just use `&#12288;` in HTML editor mode to new line is OK, [This is my GitHub Bio](https://github.com/ZengjfOS)