# How can I insert BLANK lines between lists in BitBucket Markdown?

Tags: bitbucket, markdown

BitBucket Markdown has a simplified features set to avoid HTML insertion etc. Whatever the reasons are, I can not find a way to insert blank lines between lists.

Please do not redirect me to [How to write one new line in Bitbucket markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385334/how-to-write-one-new-line-in-bitbucket-markdown), because this is NOT the same case, that case is about breaking the line and not inserting a blank line.

With the following text:

```
# This is the problem:

* Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium
    * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    * consectetur adipiscing elit
    * sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
* At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum
    * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    * consectetur adipiscing elit
    * sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt

* Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem

    * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    * consectetur adipiscing elit
    * sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

I obtain this output:

[image: Mardown rendering by BitBucket]

The problem is the lack of enough space in the transition from inner bullet paragraphs to outer bullet paragraphs, pointed by red arrows here (blue arrows show correct spacing):

[image: Good in blue, Bad in red]

If a BLANK LINE can be inserted, that can be a workaround (more or less), but I can't find a way (I have tried HTML, escape sequences, Unicode break chars etc).

Comment: this would have to be changed in the CSS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Type two spaces to the end of the last line.
2. Leave a blank line between the two lists.
3. Insert a zero-width Unicode character in the blank line. You can copy a zero-width space from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space#Usage).

---

**Example**

```
* Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium
    * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    * consectetur adipiscing elit
    * sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt<space><space>
<zero-width character>
* At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum
    * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    [...]
```

**Result**

[image: result of the code below]

Comment: Thanks, it was difficult to copy the ```<zero-width character>``` , I did it copying two consecutive words without the start of the first and the end of the second, then I deleted all characters from the beginning  and then from the end. the "nothing" that remains was in fact the ```<zero-width character>```